# Android "Focusable in touch mode" flag random behaviour

Tags: android, user-interface, listview

I having an Activity with a ListView component,
where each row having something like
EditText1, EditText2, EditText3, CheckBox1

All this components creating and adding to LinearLayout programmatically in getView method... Also editors creating enabled or disabled due to program logic:

```
editor.setEnabled(field.isEditable());
```

Well, initially all editors in all rows and columns 
had a good focus properties

**isFocusable: true, isFocusableInTouchMode: true**

But then I added a code to explicitly set focusability for editors:

```
editor.setEnabled(field.isEditable());  

editor.setFocusable(field.isEditable());
```

after that editors generating in a strange way:
some of them have a both focus properties on

**isFocusable: true, isFocusableInTouchMode: true**

but some of them generating without focus in touch mode:

**isFocusable: true, isFocusableInTouchMode: false**

so then I'm having problems when calling **requestFocus();**

Why UI view can acquire such undefined behaviour with *isFocusableInTouchMode()* - "neighbor" to *isFocusable()* flag when I programmatically set him **setFocusable()** with **true** parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems listview haven't doing a new view everytime,
and for example if I can see on a full screen

```
row1
row2 (not focusable)
row3
row4
row5
```

then, when I scroll down to

```
row6
row7 <--
row8
row9
row10
```

a row7 will inherit all the properties of row2.
It seems like a rows generated on a screen a reusing as a template for drawing all other rows. Continuing to dive into fundamentals of ListView

Comment: I'm sorry, I was newbie don't understanding view holder pattern and how it works...